# Pre-calculus- Finding the sum of $1.2+2.3x+3.4x^2...$ where $|x|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic-progressions

> Find the sum of $1.2+2.3x+3.4x^2...\infty$ where $|x|<1$

I have got the $\mathbb{n^{th}\quad term \quad= n(n+1)(x^{n-1})}$

Then I tried finding $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty n(n+1)(x^{n-1})$ but it's in product form so couldn't.

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Integrate twice to get a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(x)$ be our sum.

Thus,
$$\int\limits_0^x\left(\int\limits_0^xS(x)dx\right)dx=x^2+x^3+...=\frac{x^2}{1-x},$$
which says
$$S(x)=\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)''=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}.$$

For the solution without calculus you can use the following idea.
$$1+2x+3x^2+...=(1+x+x^2+...)+(x+x^2+...)+...=$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{1-x}=...=\frac{1}{1-x}(1+x+x^2+...)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$ and
$$1\cdot2+2\cdot3x+3\cdot4x^2+...=2\left((1+2x+3x^2+...)+(x+2x^2+3x^3+...)+...\right)=$$
$$=2\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+...\right)=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}.$$
Because $$1\cdot2=2\cdot(1);$$
$$2\cdot3=2(2+1);$$
$$3\cdot4=2(3+2+1);$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$n(n+1)=2(n+(n-1)+...+1)=2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: @Abcd Because $1+x+x^2+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: @Abcd It's a sum of the geometric progression. If $|q|<1$, $q\neq0$ then $S=a_1+a_2+...=\frac{a_1}{1-q}$. In our case $a_1=1$ and $q=x$.

Comment: @Abcd I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you know what
$$f(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots$$
is. Then
$$f'(x)=2+2\times 3x+3\times 4x^2+4\times 5x^3+\cdots.$$
Exactly what you want!

Perhaps you already know what $f(x)$ is, or maybe now you
have a clue about how to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n+1)x^n
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
xf(x)
&=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n+1)x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n+1)x^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n-1)x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f(x)-xf(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n(n+1)-n(n-1))x^{n}
=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n}
$
or
$f(x)
=\dfrac{2}{1-x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n}
$.

Similarly,
if
$g(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n}
$
then
$xg(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n+1}
=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n-1)x^{n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)x^{n}
$
so
$g(x)-xg(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-(n-1))x^{n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}
=\dfrac{x}{1-x}
$
and
$g(x)
=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$.

Therefore
$f(x)
=\dfrac{2}{1-x}g(x)
=\dfrac{2x}{(1-x)^3}
$.

Your sum is
$\dfrac{f(x)}{x}
=\dfrac{2}{(1-x)^3}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following recurrence:

$$t_n-2t_{n-1}+t_{n-2}=(n+1)(n+2)-2n(n+1)+(n-1)n=2.$$

Then summation from $0$ to $n$ with a factor $x^k$ yields (with $t_{-1}=t_{-2}=0$),

$$S_n-2S_{n-1}+S_{n-2}=(1-2x+x^2)S_n=2\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$

Hence

$$S_\infty=\frac2{(1-x)^3}.$$

This is validated bythe following check:

$$\frac2{0.99^3}=2.06\,12\,20\,30\,42\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}
(1-x)^{-n}
&=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom {-n}r (-x)^r\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom {n+r-1}r(-1)^r x^r\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {n+r-1}r x^r\end{align}$$
The required summation is 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^\infty r(r+1)x^{r-1}
&=2\sum_{r=1}^\infty \binom {r+1}2 x^{r-1}\\
&=2\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom {r+2}2 x^r\\
&=2\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom {r+2}r x^r\\
&=2\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom {3+r-1}r x^r\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 2{(1-x)^3}}\end{align}$$